# Typescript, monkey-patching an Array instance (not global)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Suppose I have an array

`const myArray = [1,2,3,4]`

Now suppose I want to add properties to this array

`myArray.sum = function(){return this.reduce( (a:number,b:number)=>a+b )}`

I receive "Property 'sum' does not exist on type 'number[]'"

How do I do this in Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

```
// ignore types
(myArray as any).sum(...);

// patch it
interface X extends Array<number> {
  sum(...): number
}
const myArray: X = [1,2,3,4] as X
myArray.sum = function() { ... };
```

If it is one-off, I would do the first one most of the time.